# how can I run the ssh-agent auto in the zsh environment?

Tags: linux, debian, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I use the zsh and the oh-my-zsh.
When I use the github and want to use the key to upload.

I always find the

```
#git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Because I have not add the key

```
#ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.
```

so I have to start the ssh-agent and add the key when I want to push or pull

```
#ssh-agent zsh
#ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

How can I add these command in the script,so I don't need type the commands?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

#### open .zshrc in a text editor:

```
vim ~/.zshrc
```

Add ssh-agent to the plugins list and save:

```
plugins=(git ssh-agent)
```

You may want to immediately reload your .zshrc settings:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Comment: It can run ssh-agent now,but how can it "ssh-add -l" automatically?

Comment: You can use this: `zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities id_rsa id_rsa2 id_github` (found here: https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/ssh-agent/ssh-agent.plugin.zsh)

Comment: The readme is a little more clear. https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent

Comment: The problem is that the passphrase isn't stored once you've logged out. Apparently on a Mac, you can add `ssh-add -K` to your `.zshrc` file to use the keychain but this doesn't work on Linux.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with powerlevel10k.

Comment: For me it works with Powerlevel10K, however, I get an error message the first time I start a new shell since the plugin creates output. This only happens once though.

Comment: There are some powerlevel10k specifics here: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/ssh-agent#powerline-10k-specific-settings